# Is it possible to access ThreadLocal variable given a thread object

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to access thread local variable in another thread.

e.g.

I have Thread object A for thread-1,

it has one local variable L1.

and I have another thread Thread-2, how can I access L1 in Thread-2 ? Thanks

Comment: No. It would violate the meaning of `thread-local`. If you don't want it to be thread-local, don't use `ThreadLocal` for it.

Comment: Put the variable in the parent class

Comment: It is in another third party library, I can not change that. :(

Comment: If it's in a third-party library, you almost definitely don't want to go around messing with their threading assumptions. Multithreading is a pretty precise thing, and if they create a ThreadLocal that you somehow "steal" into another thread, it could easily break in subtle and confusing ways.

Comment: @zjffdu If it's in a third-party libfrary you are violating their design. They made it thread-local because they wanted it to be thread-local. Don't do this.

Answer (score 2):

No because memory visibility. All the ThreadLocal infrastructure assumes that access to the threadlocal objects is thread-confined. If another thread tampers with the contents of a threadLocal object, there's no memory barrier to let the original owner thread know it needs to update its cached version of that object, and the JIT wouldn't know to take into account modifications from other threads when reasoning about what instructions it can reorder; if you update it the original thread could still be seeing a stale version with no clue a change took place.

This is in addition to the observation made by yshavit that tampering with the internals of a third-party library is a bad idea in general.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, using reflection. However **you must not**. For the very reasons that others have pointed out : you're bound to break things, or get unexpected results.

But purely for the academic demonstration that it is possible, this method does what you ask :

```
@NotThreadSafe
Object getValueForThread(ThreadLocal<?> threadLocal, Thread thread) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchFieldException {
    Method getMap = ThreadLocal.class.getDeclaredMethod("getMap", new Class<?>[]{Thread.class});
    getMap.setAccessible(true);
    Object map = getMap.invoke(threadLocal, thread);
    Class<?> clazz = map.getClass();
    Method getEntry = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getEntry", new Class<?>[]{ThreadLocal.class});
    getEntry.setAccessible(true);
    Object entry = getEntry.invoke(map, threadLocal);
    Field value = entry.getClass().getDeclaredField("value");
    value.setAccessible(true);
    return value.get(entry);
}
```

Or at least, it may do what you ask. As there are no visibility guarantees, the thread that invokes this method may see stale values. So once more : **don't do this**.